# Light in my living room is not working

Tags: electrical, light-fixture

I have electricity on cables but won't work any light bulb I try on.

In the first picture, is the light is not working.
 In the second picture is the light that is working.
I tried to switch them in every way. Not working. 
And when I check if is electricity in wires, it is(picture 3)

[image][image][image]

Comment: Does "electricity on cable" mean you have wiring in the wall bringing power to an outlet in the wall? Does it mean that you've got an extension cord plugged into an outlet that your light is plugged into? Does it mean that you've plugged the lamp directly into the outlet, but the lamp doesn't work even if you put a brand new bulb in? Please [edit] your post to clarify that. What does "I check the wires with lamp control" mean? I'm guessing that English isn't your first language, and that's fine - you speak it better than I speak any other language, just trying to clarify your meaning.

Comment: No. I mean from the spot the light wires should come out from wall.  Where the light supposed to be. I am putting the light bulb support. And nothing happens.

Comment: Sorry about my English   yes. I plugged the lamp directly to the outlet but the lamp is not working. Even with a new light bulb. "I check the wires with lamp control" means that I check if is electricity on wires. And there is.  But the light is not working.

Comment: What are you using to test for the presence of electricity at the fixture?

Comment: Like I said, your English is _way_ better than my "any other language", no worries! Can you take a picture and [edit] it into your post so we can see exactly what's going on? Sometimes that helps far more than words do.

Comment: I did it. Is edited now.

Comment: Is this a new light or an old one that just stopped working?

Comment: Is the old one. But I tried to put it everywhere in my apartment. Is working. That's the only spot where is not working.

Comment: those are two different light fixture in Picture  1 & 2.  Pic 1 is a 3-buld ceiling fixture.  Pic 2 is a 2-buld wall fixture.  What does the light fixture in Pic 2 have to do with the light fixture in Pic 1 not working?

Comment: Does one light switch control both lights?